# How do I make things (e.g. tomcat) run after cloud-init has run the userdata script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

Short version:

How do I make init.d scripts run after cloud-init has run the `userdata` script on an EC2?

Long version:

Our deployment process is to construct AMIs with everything installed on them (tomcat, nginx, application etc), but with certain configuration values missed out.  At boot time, the userdata script adds in the missing configuration values, and then the application stack can start up

Our current EC2s are based on an old version of the official Debian AMIs, which have the script `ec2-run-user-data`.  This script runs at boot, and downloads and runs the EC2s userdata.  When constructing the AMI, I simple edit the init.d scripts for tomcat, nginx etc to include ec2-run-user-data in their "Required-Start:" line, so they start up after the userdata has been run.

Unfortunately that approach is no longer viable, as we want to start using the hvm base AMIs, which have cloud-init installed rather than ec2-run-user-data.  But I can't figure out how cloud-init works well enough to work out how to make the process work.

As far as I can tell, the userdata script is run by the cloud-final step, but cloud-final has $all in it's "Required-Start:" line.  I could remove it, but I don't know what consequences that might have.

I've tried making tomcat etc run after cloud-init or cloud-config, but the userdata hasn't run by then.  Also, it looks like cloud-init and cloud-config start processes then exit, which might explain why cloud-final needs to have $all in Required-Start

More Info:

1. We use the 'baked AMI' approach, where we create an AMI with all the packages/applications installed, then tell the existing Autoscaling Groups to replace their EC2s with new ones based on the new AMI (via CloudFormation).  Some configuration information isn't known at baking time, but must be inserted via the userdata script.
2. When our tomcat app starts up it expects to read in the file /etc/appname/application.conf.  That file has the text `<<REPLACE_THIS>>` in it.  Tomcat will fail to start up if it tries to run before `<<REPLACE_TIME>>` has been replaced
3. The userdata script is something like:

   `#!/bin/bash
   sed -i 's!<<REPLACE_TIME>>!{New value to use, determined at deploy time}!' /etc/appname/application.conf`
4. The default Required-Start for tomcat is "$local_fs $remote_fs $network".  At baking time, I change that to "$local_fs $remote_fs $network ec2-run-user-data"

By doing all that, the text in /etc/appname/application.conf gets replaced before tomcat runs.  But as I said above, I want to change to using cloud-init, and I can't figure out what I need to do to make tomcat start after cloud-init has run the userdata.  I get the impression that cloud-init doesn't run the userdata until very late in the process.  I could change the userdata script to contain "/etc/init.d/tomcat restart" at the end, but it seems a bit dumb to have tomcat fail to start then get restarted.

Comment: I suggest to give some sample codes to show us what you are talking about, such as userdata file, `ec2-run-user-data`

Comment: Second, if you need make tomcat run automatically, when install tomcat, you should set the auto-start script under /etc/init.d and rc3.d, then you needn't manually edit something in userdata.

Comment: @SamBarham I'm facing an almost identical issue - did you get a solution?

Comment: We did, but I'm a bit fuzzy on the details.  I think part of the solution was to put bash scripts in /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-once and /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot, but I think was also managed to rewrite things somehow so that we didn't need to do any text replacement in the config files.